# how do tcp servers work if there is no multicasting?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

i am wondering how tcp servers work because there is no multicasting. I am interested in using tcp for my game since it won't require to much packets to be sent like  some other games. It still needs to have a client / server architecture though.

Since there is no multicasting, is there just a loop to send everything directly from server to client for every client? Is this what minecraft does (cuz i read it uses tcp)

it was my understanding that only 1 socket can be bound to a port. With udp, the server socket can accept connections from IPAdress.Any, so it can receive information from all clients. Since TCP is connection only, how would this work? Can multiple TCP connections be made on the same socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one listening connection can exist per port on the server. However, many clients can connect to that one listening port. A "Connection" under the hood is the combination of `ServerIP + ServerPort + ClientIP + ClientPort`, also the client port does not need to be the same every time (only the server side port needs to stay static), the OS chooses a random high number port and give that to the client side for the connection. That is why you can have many outgoing connections on a client but only one listening connection on the server.

Look at [this page](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) for a example on how to set up multiple connections to one port.